# Чёрный экран в VirtualBox c Kali Linux

Tags: virtualbox, kali-linux

Установил на VirtualBox Kali Linux, вроде настроил всё правильно(выделил 2 гб ОЗУ,дал 2 ядра от проца, поставил PAE/NX в настройках процессора) - запускаю Kali Linux - логинюсь, всё нормально открывается(командная строка, проги), проходит минуты 3-4 и на тебе - полностью чёрный экран без курсора, пробовал открывать Kali раз 15, все ровно после 3-4 минут этот грёбаный чёный экран, что делать? OC - Windows 7, система 32-битная, 3 гб RAM, процессор - AMD Athlon(tm)II X3 400e Processor 2.20 GHz.

Comment: Не пишите, пожалуйста, словами "вопрос ни на что не похож", это кликбейт и так делать - моветон. Опишите в подробностях, чем именно уникальна ваша проблема, что именно удалось предпринять. Используйте много букв, если нужно.

Comment: похоже, что врубается заставка